# kMVC Nuget Package Installation "methods is null" Error

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, nuget, knockout-mvc

I have been trying out Knockout MVC (kMVC) for use in our intranet apps for a couple of weeks now and I am getting the error ("methods is null") when installing the kMVC package via nuget on all of our existing and newly created sample ASP.NET MVC 4 projects. I tried it on a couple of different machines one with VS 2017 and the other VS 2019 I still get the same error message.

Comment: This package is too old, the install.ps1 can't work well in VS2015~VS2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have been trying out Knockout MVC (kMVC) for use in our intranet
>   apps for a couple of weeks now and I am getting the error ("methods is
>   null") when installing the kMVC package via nuget.

This package is too old(never update since 8/12/2014) so it's not that compatible with VS2015~VS2019.

**Details:**

You can find a `packages` folder in your solution directory, there you can find the `kMVC.0.6.0` folder. This folder contains the `PerpetuumSoft.Knockout.dll` in `lib` sub-folder and `install.ps1` in `tools` sub-folder.

When we install that nuget package, nuget will help our project to reference that assembly, and run the powershell script automatically. The `method is null` issue results from that.

See content of `Install.ps1` in that nuget package:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

$projectIsVB = $false
try {
    $item = $project.ProjectItems.Item("global.asax").ProjectItems.Item("global.asax.cs")
} catch {
    $item = $project.ProjectItems.Item("global.asax").ProjectItems.Item("global.asax.vb")
    $projectIsVB = $true
}

if ($projectIsVB) {
    $class = $item.FileCodeModel.CodeElements | where-object {$_.Kind -eq 1}
} else {
    $namespace = $item.FileCodeModel.CodeElements | where-object {$_.Kind -eq 5}
    $class = $namespace.Children | where-object {$_.Kind -eq 1}
}

$method = $class.Children | where-object {$_.Name -eq "Application_Start"}
if (!$method)
{
    [system.windows.forms.messagebox]::show("methods is null")
}

$edit = $method.StartPoint.CreateEditPoint();
$edit.LineDown()
$edit.CharRight(1)
$edit.Insert([Environment]::NewLine)
if ($projectIsVB) {
    $edit.Insert("      ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new PerpetuumSoft.Knockout.KnockoutModelBinder()")
    $edit.Insert([Environment]::Newline)
} else {
    $edit.Insert("      ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new PerpetuumSoft.Knockout.KnockoutModelBinder();")
}
```

So if we install this nuget package in MVC project, it will try to add one line `ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new PerpetuumSoft.Knockout.KnockoutModelBinder();` to `Application_Start` method in `global.asax.cs` file.

I tried it in VS2012, it **works well without any issue**. But in VS2015~VS2019, it throws `method is null` warning. I think this is because the `project system or VS SDK` has changed a lot in these versions, so the code in `install.ps1` can't work well any more.

**Here're some suggestions to your original issue:**

1.You can try to contact the author to ask if they plan to update this package to support VS2017~VS2019.

2.It's just a little message from the author, it won't actually affect anything in your project.(It won't affect your build or development) So you can easily ignore this messagebox.

And all the `install.ps1` wants to do is to add the `ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new KnockoutModelBinder();` to Application_Start method, so just ignore the warning and add this line manually.

> As for your another issue `How do I set the default binder to both?`

The `line2` will cover `line1` in Application_Start method, so only line2 works in that situation. And to find a workaround to set them both(related to coding), I suggest you can open an new thread with more details since it's not related to your original issue(related to nuget package). Please avoid asking two different questions in one issue.

Hope all above makes some help:)